# How do I randomly select ONE row in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Pls what query do I need to randomly select JUST ONE ROW in my table?

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0,1;
```

and it seems very slow and sometimes doesnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity ... how would it sometimes not work?

Answer (score 1):

If the table is large, `ORDER BY` will be slow.  Instead you can just pick a random offset based on the number of rows in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?
```

Where `?` is some random number < `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`

Comment: I can't count the number of times this question has been asked using all my digits ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `STORED PROCEDURE` which contains a Dynamic SQL to get random record,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SelectOne()
BEGIN
    SET @rownum := (SELECT count(*) FROM TableName);
    SET @start := (SELECT FLOOR((rand() * @rownum)));
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT ?, 1');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @start;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;        
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43948/4)

thanks to [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) for improvement `:)`

Comment: Nice implementation of Explosion's answer :) why don't you add this on the mentioned dupe? Though granted, this is only good for selecting exactly one.

Comment: Nice! Though, I would use `FLOOR(RAND() * @rownum)` and have `@rownum` equal to just `count()`, otherwise you starve the first record. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43948/4

Comment: good idea @Jack . let me try that `:)`

Comment: Oh, and of course, it should be mentioned that a simple `COUNT(*)` has a different runtime when you use InnoDB :)

Comment: @Jack I added your improvement on the answer `:)`

Comment: This worked for me: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR( MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `table` ) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;